# Dynamic binding of mostly unrelated objects after object implementation

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have 3 objects that I want to dynamically bind and use a specific set of functions that they all share in common.  I know I can create a parent class with virtual functions and have the these objects be derivations from that, but is there any way to get the same effect without doing that?

Edit:
I am talking about 3 different class's that have a couple functions that I want to use after I have created one (depends on user input).  But I don't want to edit these original classes in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you mean by "dynamic binding", "unrelated objects" and "shared functions" (if you explain these points, you will receive more clear answers).
But if you are talking about three objects (not classes) that have some common data and set of identical functions to manage them, consider static fields for data.

**EDIT**: example with static data

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CommonDataForObjects
{
private:
 int id; // personal data of object
 static int maxID; // commom data for all objects
 static int activeID; // also commom data for all objects
public:
 CommonDataForObjects()
 {
  // when object created generate new id
  maxID++;
  id = maxID;
 }
 
 int setAsActive()
 {
  // remember the id of prevoius active
  int prevID = activeID;
  // change active id to id ot object for which this method is called
  activeID = id;
  // return the id of prevoius active object
  return prevID;
 }

};

int CommonDataForObjects::maxID = 0;
int CommonDataForObjects::activeID = 0;

int main()
{
 CommonDataForObjects obj1;
 CommonDataForObjects obj2;
 CommonDataForObjects obj3;
 // testing
 cout << "Making obj2 the active... previus active was " << obj2.setAsActive() << endl;
 cout << "Making obj1 the active... previus active was " << obj1.setAsActive() << endl;
 cout << "Making obj3 the active... previus active was " << obj3.setAsActive() << endl;
}
```